# Is the following always prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

For a given $k$ define

$$s_k = 1 + \prod_{i=1}^k p_i$$
$$t_k = \text{NextPrime}(s_k)$$
$$v_k = t_k - s_k +1$$

Where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number.

**Conjecture: $v_k$ is prime**

Example: 
$$k=3$$
$$s_3 = 1+(2)(3)(5)=31$$
$$t_3 = 37 $$
$$v_3 = 37-31 +1 = 7 \,\text{(prime)} $$

Tested numerically up to $k=400$ and it seems to hold.

Comment: can you please share your program?

Comment: Note $\ v_k = t_k - 2\cdot 3\cdots p_k\,$ is coprime to $\,2,3,\ldots, p_k\ \ $

Comment: As @AccidentalFourierTransform notes, this sequence has received some attention. For that matter, easy plausibility/probabilistic heuristic arguments around the Prime Number Theorem strongly suggest that it is asymptotically true. E.g., maybe RH implies it's asymptotically true. Surely less than RH would give something, etc.

Comment: one plus any prime give an even number which can be written as the sum of two primes smaller than the initial prime.moving the primes before the initial prime gives your relation. unless one proves opposite.

Comment: This is known as Fortune's conjecture

Comment: If next prime is within ${p_{k+1}}^2$ it's guaranteed as until then only distances would be forced to be 1 less than a prime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is sequence [A005235](http://oeis.org/A005235) on OEIS. It is conjectured to always be prime, although it is not known yet. Check the page for useful remarks and references.